# Boxing flip effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

```css
.grey-background {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 85px 0 60px;
}
.flip-box {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.flip-box-before {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.714em;
  padding: 44px 40px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

.flip-box-before:hover + .flip-box-after {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 11111;
}

.flip-box-before:hover + .flip-box-before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.flip-box-after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.143em;
  top: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  color: #999;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-background">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="flip-box">
        <div class="flip-box-before">free shipping</div>
        <div class="flip-box-after">on all orders over $100</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="flip-box">
        <div class="flip-box-before">free return</div>
        <div class="flip-box-after">free 90 days return</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to replicate this [example](http://delphinus.demo.arw.tf/?___store=german).

Below (in the site) you will find exactly what I mean.

Can you tell me why my example does not work properly? I do not know what is incomplete and lacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following was the mistake in your original code:

- The selector `.flip-box-before:hover + .flip-box-before` is wrong. It is trying to apply style to an element with `class = 'flip-box-before'`  which is also the sibling of another element with the same class. There is obviously no such element in your markup and hence the `transform` that's specified within this selector never gets applied (and as a result the default text doesn't move).

Another correction that I'd suggest is to apply the `transform` while hovering on the `.flip-box` which is the container element instead of `.flip-box-before`. This is because `.flip-box-before` element is ***getting translated during the hover*** and it may result in the mouse pointer actually being outside the element's new boundaries. Since the mouse maybe outside the new boundaries at transition end, the reverse effect (hover out) effect might automatically get triggered without we actually hovering out of the box (and thus causing a jittery effect). Applying the `:hover` on the `.flip-box` would avoid this as the container is not moving at any point of time.

Here's how you do it: (*In the snippet the boxes are not in the same line as I haven't included bootstrap libraries.* ***This [pen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JEJzej) uses the same code as below with bootstrap.***)

```css
.grey-background {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 85px 0 60px;
}
.flip-box {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flip-box-before {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.714em;
  padding: 44px 40px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-after {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 11111;
}
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-before {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}
.flip-box-after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.143em;
  top: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transform: translate(0px, -100%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  color: #999;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-background">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="flip-box">
        <div class="flip-box-before">free shipping</div>
        <div class="flip-box-after">on all orders over $100</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="flip-box">
        <div class="flip-box-before">free return</div>
        <div class="flip-box-after">free 90 days return</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```